# Does solidity optimize gas usage based on total storage used before and after a contract method is called?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Here is a simple contract to demonstrate what I am asking:

```
contract Example {
  uint256 intOne;
  uint256 intTwo;

  function test1()
    public
    payable
  {
    intOne = 300;
  }

  function test2()
    public
    payable
  {
    intOne = 0;
    intTwo = 300;
  }
}
```

After freshly deploying the contract, I first called `test1()` and it used 41527 gas.

This made sense to me since writing `intOne` from zero to non-zero will use 20,000 gas, plus base line gas usage (however that works).

I then called `test2` which surprisingly used only 31453 gas.

Shouldn't changing `intOne` from non-zero to zero cost 5000, then another 20,000 to change `intTwo` from zero to non-zero?

Or is solidity able to calculate the difference in total storage used before and after the transaction to determine the amount of gas used?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32419/is-refunded-gas-for-freed-storage-given-to-the-contract-the-allocator-or-t

I was not aware of gas being refunded for zeroing out a word.